# How to check if an include() returned anything?

Tags: php, include, return

Is there any way to check if an included document via `include('to_include.php')` has returned anything?

This is how it looks:

```
//to_include.php
echo function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times();

//main_document.php
include('to_include.php');
if($the_return_of_the_include != '') { 
    echo $do_a_little_dance_make_a_little_love_get_down_tonight; 
}
```

So after I've included `to_include.php` in my main document I would like to check if anything was generated by the included document.

I know the obvious solution would be to just use `function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times()` in the `main_document.php`, but that's not possible in my current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times()` return something when it outputs something and set a variable:

```
//to_include.php
$ok=function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times();

//main_document.php
$ok='';
include('to_include.php');
if($ok != '') { 
    echo $do_a_little_dance_make_a_little_love_get_down_tonight; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about generated output you can use:

```
ob_start();
include "MY_FILEEEZZZ.php";
function_that_generates_html_in_include();
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
if(!empty($string)) { // Or any other check
    echo $some_crap_that_makes_my_life_difficult;
}
```

Might have to tweak the ob_ calls... I think that's right from memory, but memory is that of a goldfish.

You could also just set the contents of variable like `$GLOBALS['done'] = true;` in the include file when it generates something and check for that in your main code.

Answer (score 1):

Given the wording of the question, it sounds as if you want this:

```
//to_include.php
return function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times();

//main_document.php
$the_return_of_the_include = include 'to_include.php';
if (empty($the_return_of_the_include)) { 
    echo $do_a_little_dance_make_a_little_love_get_down_tonight; 
} else {
    echo $the_return_of_the_include;
}
```

Which should work in your situation. That way you don't have to worry about output buffering, variable creep, *etc*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point of the question but ....

```
function_exists();
```

Will return true if the function is defined.

```
include()
```

returns true if the file is inclued.

so wrap either or both in an if() and you're good to go, unless I got wrong end of the stick

```
if(include('file.php') && function_exists(my_function))
{
 // wee
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights, but whether or not the file is included is not the issue. My question's about wether or not the included file generated anything. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: function_exists() will test if the function in the included file exists. if you want to see if it will output surely you just get the function to return a value...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// to_include.php
$returnvalue = function_that_generates_some_html_sometimes_but_not_all_the_times();
echo $returnvalue;

//main_document.php
include('to_include.php');
if ( $returnvalue != '' ){
   echo $do_a_little_dance_make_a_little_love_get_down_tonight; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! But catalin was first ;-)